# Posts edited count on profile is way less than my revsions count?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits, profile-page

According to my profile I've edited one post as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3554833/script47). However if I click the link, it says 59 revisions. So is this a bug or am I missing something? Image below to show you what I mean.

[image]

Comment: Probably server-side [caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

Comment: Server-side not client-side. It will probably fix itself after a while.

Comment: @TinyGiant understood, it has been like this for a day or two now, any ideas when it should refresh?

Comment: @Script47 Answer: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: I have no idea when that script runs, it could be daily, weekly or even monthly.

Comment: Also somewhat relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/193623/288751

Comment: Not the problem the OP is having, but if you notice your profile is off too, it's likely because the top right "posts edited" probabably only counts a post 1 time, whereas the revisions tab can count each edit to the same post, so if you made 3 edits on your post, it'll count 3 there and only 1 at top right.

Comment: shows 3 posts edited and 94 revisions currently, must be some very good caching going on

Comment: shows 6 posts edited and 161 revisions now...

Answer (score 9):

Under `/revisions` you see every entry of  PostHistory table that you contributed: that is, every action that resulted in a new version of some post.

But the count of edits (used for issuing badges and for the profile display) does not include retags or edits to own questions; it also counts multiple edits to the same post as one.

**Reference**: [Edits vs Revisions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138232).

Answer (score 4):

The reason for this is that the "X posts edited" on your profile only counts certain edits, where as "All Actions -> Revisions" counts *all* edits.

In "X posts edited", revisions to your own posts do not count and multiple revisions to the same post only count once. There may be other criteria I'm missing, but these are the ones I know of.